# Ajax request inside ajax request fails - reloads the whole page again

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

So, basicly what I'm trying to achieve:
In index.php
I would enter products code to search for products information and it's images (that query is run in open_first.php, called via ajax post request).
It works just perfect..

When open_first.php is loaded, it displays me some images I can select from (when I click on the image, it's relevant checkbox get's checked containing the image id).
This works too, just fine.

BUT,
If I enter a code in the field: "productCodeCopy" and click on "confirmCodeCopy" -button it reloads the whole page, I mean index.php and everything I've entered is lost and I'm back in the starting point again. I don't understand why it does so. I suppose it has something to do with the fact, that the second ajax request is made from a dynamically created page (open_first.php)?? Do I miss something I should POST too?? Or what's the problem, this is really frustrating me since I've tried to fix this for hours now.

Note:
Jquery is loaded in index.php, open_first.php and open_second.php, I've just ignored that to keep the code simpler.

FILE: index.php (the "starting point")

```
<!-- head -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#confirmCode").on('click', function(){
    var productCode = $("#productCode").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'open_first.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: ({code: productCode}),
        success: function(data){
            $("#found").html(data);
        },
        error: _alertError
    });
    function _alertError() {
        alert('error on request');
    }
    });
});
</script>

<!-- body -->
<input type="text" class="textfields" id="productCode" name="productCode" value="YT-6212">
<input type="button" class="admin-buttons green" name="confirmCode" id="confirmCode" value="Search">
<div id="found"></div>
```

FILE open_first.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#foundImage").on('click', function(){
            $('#foundImage').toggleClass("foundImage-selected foundImage");
            var myID = $('#foundImage').data('image-id');
            var checkBox = $('input[id=selectedImages-'+myID+']');
            checkBox.prop("checked", !checkBox.prop("checked"));
        });

        $("#confirmCodeCopy").on('click', function(){
            var checkedItems = $('input:checkbox[name="selectedImages[]"]:checked');                
            // this code here reloads the whole page / view (as in "index.php")
            $.ajax({
                url: 'open_second.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: ({checked: checkedItems, copyTo: productCodeCopy, code: "<?php echo $_POST['code']; ?>"}),
                success: function(data){
                    $("#copyToProducts").append(data);
                },
                error: _alertError
            });
            /*
            // the code below runs just fine when I hit the button "confirmCodeCopy"
            alert('Fuu');
            return false;
            */
        });

        function _alertError() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
</script>
<!--BODY-->
<!-- these are dynamically generated from php, just to simplify we have checkbox that contains value "1" to be posted in ajax -->
<div class="foundImage" id="foundImage" data-image-id="1"><img src="image.jpg"><input type="checkbox" id="selectedImages-1" name="selectedImages[]" value="1" style="display: none;"></div>
<label for="productCodeCopy">Products code</label>
<input type="text" class="textfields" id="productCodeCopy" name="productCodeCopy">
<br /><br />
<label for="confirmCodeCopy">&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" class="admin-buttons green" name="confirmCodeCopy" id="confirmCodeCopy" value="Search">
<div id="copyToProducts"></div>
```

open_second.php only prints out POST variables for now, so nothing special yet.

SOLVED

So ok, I solved it. With dumdum's help.

I removed the line:

```
$('input:checkbox[name="selectedImages[]"]:checked');
```

And added this:

```
var checkedItems = new Array();
var productToCopy = $('#productCodeCopy').val();
$("input:checkbox[name=selectedImages[]]:checked").each(function() {
    checkedItems.push($(this).val());
});
```

Since there was no form element present, it didn't get the field values unless "manually retrieved" via .val() -function.. Stupid me..

I don't know how much this affected but I changed also:

```
data: ({checked: checkedItems, copyTo: productCodeCopy"})
```

To

```
data: {"checked": checkedItems, "copyTo": productToCopy}
```

So now it's working just fine :) Cool!

Comment: does your button live inside a FORM element? If yes can you add it to the code sample

Comment: also, you're sure that open_second.php is returning data, not an HTTP redirect or something?

Comment: Hi
There are no form elements on the page and it's just printing out variables but I tried to just add the word "Hello" to the file but no effect whatsoever :)

Answer (score 1):

WHen you apply event hander to a button or a link to do ajax...always prevent the browser default processing of the click on that element

There are 2 ways. Using either `preventDefault()` or returning `false` from handler

```
$("#confirmCodeCopy").on('click', function(event){
  /* method one*/
  event.preventDefault();
  /* handler code here*/

  /* method 2*/
  return false;

})
```

The same is true for adding a submit handler to a form to do ajax with form data rather than having the form redirect to it's action url

Comment: It does not work, I've tried that earlier :) It still reloads the page :(
( I could have left that code on, though, but removed it from the original ones too since it did not do the trick this time..)

Comment: then you haven't shown all the code involved, and/or are throwing script errors in page. Look in browser console for errors

Answer (score 0):

your code `$('input:checkbox[name="selectedImages[]"]:checked');` is returning *undefined* making the json data in the ajax call invalid.   Check you selector there.

Comment: Ok.. I tried removing the checkboxes and all references to them it the code. Now I get an Jquery error: "NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument". I'm using Mozilla. In IE it says "Stack overflow at line 2".. Interesting...

Comment: So basicly now I'm only posting.. trying to post the value in field: "productCodeCopy"